# Preposition problem in or on

Tags: grammar, prepositions, grammaticality

I have a dobt that which one is correct

> he is in the chair
>
> he is on the chair

Which one is right and why?

Answer (score 1):

**he is in the chair ....he is on the chair .....Which one is right and why?**

**Both are correct.**

He sat on the dining room chair

He sat back in his chair and browsed the newspaper.

It depends on what type of chair. A dinning room chair is most often just a seat with a back. You sit on it, like you would a stool. Whilst a fire side chair is usually of the type that has arms and a high back. You sit in it, like you would in a bath.

**on** preposition [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on) (**ABOVE**): used to show that something is in a position above something else and touching it, or that something is moving into such a position:

**in** preposition [Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in) (**INSIDE**): inside a container, place, or area, or surrounded or closed off by something: